# Substitute for MAX865EUA-T

Tags: power-supply, component-selection, charge-pump, substitution

It's been few weeks I'm searching for a substitute for my MAX865EUA-T ([datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2304140030_Analog-Devices-Inc--Maxim-Integrated-MAX865EUA-T_C133210.pdf)). I need a component able to do a +10V/-10V output with a +5V input, this component was perfect for me since it's really compact and works up to 100mA but unfortunately it's out of stock.

I was wondering if anyone knows a part that could replace this one.

So far the best solution I've found is to replace it with two MAX660ESA+T ([datasheet](https://atta.szlcsc.com/upload/public/pdf/source/20121117/1457706559551.pdf)) but it  makes a much bigger circuit and I'm afraid it will not fit on my PCB.

I'm open to any kind of suggestion since I'm completely stuck so far.

Thanks.

Comment: Mouser has >10,000 in stock of the exact part number. You should look more thoroughly.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Amazing ! Thanks ! They probably just restocked it, it wasn't available when I checked for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Digikey has 4 options](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/filter/voltage-regulators-dc-dc-switching-regulators/739?s=N4IgjCBcoEwKwyqAxlAZgQwDYGcCmANCAPZQDaIMYMAbFSALpEAOALlCAMqsBOAlgDsA5iAC%2BRMAAYAnAA4kIVJEy5CJciADMMaWGnTGLdpC69BI8eB0Roi9NnxFSkCjQDsNACz6QROJJlPCCYQNg5ufmExCTkDWyUVR3UXEElGSwBaRHioXgBXNWcKOF8QAwZRS2yKAFkAQQANWRp0oA) (maybe more) that might work.
[image]

Comment: thanks ! Looks like it does the job. I'm gonna have a hard time soldering it but it's the best solution I have so far.